# What is the algebra generated by the class $\mathcal{E}$ of sets described?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, discrete-mathematics

What is the algebra generated by the class $\varepsilon$ of sets described?

a) For a fixed subset $E$ of $S$, $\mathcal{E}=\{E\}$ is the class containing $E$ only.
b) For a fixed subset $E$ of $S$, $\mathcal{E}$ is the class of sets of which $E$ is a subset, *i.e.*: $$\mathcal{E}= \{F∶E \subseteqq F , F \subseteqq S\}$$
c) $\mathcal{E}$ is the class of all sets which contain exactly two points.

Comment: An algebra is finite unions, finite intersections and complements, so for (a) all you can get is $E$,$S-E$, $S$ and $\emptyset$.  Is that right?

Comment: @Cameron Buie thanks for your editing..

Comment: No problem. Take a look at my answer, and see if it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

As remarked in the comments above, $$\mathcal{A}=\{\emptyset,E,S\setminus E,S\}$$ is an algebra on $S,$ and is the smallest such containing $\mathcal{E}=\{E\}$.

---

For $\mathcal{E}=\{F\subseteq S:E\subseteq F\},$ note that $\mathcal{E}$ is already closed under *arbitrary* unions and intersections, so to start getting a handle on the algebra it generates, we need to consider complements first. Letting $\mathcal{A}$ be the algebra on $S$ generated by $\mathcal{E},$ we know that $S\setminus F\in\mathcal{A}$ for all $F\in\mathcal{E},$ which by definition of $\mathcal{E}$ means that every subset of $S\setminus E$ is in $\mathcal{A}.$ That is, every subset of $S$ disjoint from $E$ is an element of $\mathcal A.$ In fact, it is relatively easily shown that if $\mathcal C=\{F\subseteq S:E\cap F=\emptyset\},$ then $\mathcal E\cup\mathcal C$ is an algebra, and so is precisely $\mathcal A.$

---

For $\mathcal{E}$ the set of two-element subset of $S,$ note that every singleton subset of $S$ is the intersection of two two-element subsets, and every finite subset of $S$ is a finite union of singleton subsets of $S$. Consequently, the algebra $\mathcal{A}$ on $S$ generated by $\mathcal{E}$ will contain every finite subset of $S,$ so will also contain every subset of $S$ having a finite complement. Can you think of any other subsets of $S$ that will be in $\mathcal{A}?$ If not, can you prove that $\mathcal{A}$ contains precisely the finite subsets of $S$ and the subsets of $S$ with finite complements? If you can't think of any others and can't prove that there *aren't* any others, let me know. **Added**: As Did pointed out in the comments below, this approach does not work when $S$ has fewer than $3$ elements. Fortunately, those cases are easily dealt with individually.

Comment: In the last case, treat separately the case when the size of E is less than 3.

Comment: Good point, Did!

Comment: @cameron I think there is no others subset of $S$ that will be in $A$ since $A$ on $S$ generated by $\mathcal{E}$ the set of two-element every singleton subset of $S$. any way thank for your explanation, very clear and detail..:). any way i have difficulty to prove the finite subset of $S$ and the subsets of $S$ with finite complements, kindly can you show me? many thanks..

Comment: @Did yes, good suggestion..many thanks

Comment: @lpchristine: To prove it, let $$\mathcal{F}=\{A\subseteq S:A\text{ is finite}\}\cup\{A\subseteq S:S\setminus A\text{ is finite}\}.$$ We've determined (informally) that $\mathcal{E}\subseteq\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{A},$ and we must show that $\mathcal{F}\supseteq\mathcal{A}$. It suffices to show that $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra on $S,$ since $\mathcal{A}$ is *by definition* the smallest algebra on $S$ containing $\mathcal{E}$ as a subset.

Comment: @CameronBuie Yes,,I got the ideas...once again many thanks.....

Comment: @lpchristine: You're welcome. I just realized that my second part was fatally flawed, though! Take another look, if you're still on.

Comment: yes I see..i just realize it..